# Why is dataframe giving me row errors?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm incredibly new to R and trying to utilize some R script that was used by a previous member of the lab. I've been stuck on this part for quite some time now and could really use some help. I'm not sure what is causing this error. Any help you could give would be wonderful.

```
setwd("C:/Users/nelsjm17/Documents/Lab_Main/Egg Laying/Analyses to Use/cleaned.data/cleaned&rotated/")
April09.5 <- read.csv("C:/Users/nelsjm17/Documents/Lab_Main/Egg Laying/Analyses to Use/cleaned.data/cleaned&rotated/cleaned&rotated.april09.5eggs.cleaned.csv")
pEggs <- function(df){
# function
colnames
colnames(df)[1] <- "row.num"
df$Y <- (-1)* df$Y
borders <- df[1:5,]
planted <- df[df$Notes == "planted egg" & !is.na(df$Notes),]
eggs <- df[is.na(df$Notes),]
eggs$south <- as.logical(sp::point.in.polygon( 
point.x = eggs$X, point.y = eggs$Y,
pol.x = with( borders, c(X[1],X[5],X[4],X[5])),
pol.y = with( borders, c(Y[1],Y[5],Y[4],Y[5]*10))
))
eggs$west <- as.logical(sp::point.in.polygon( 
point.x = eggs$X, point.y = eggs$Y,
pol.x = with( borders, c(X[2],X[5],X[1],X[5]/10)),
pol.y = with( borders, c(Y[2],Y[5],Y[1],Y[5])) 
))
eggs$north <- as.logical(sp::point.in.polygon( 
point.x = eggs$X, point.y = eggs$Y,
pol.x = with( borders, c(X[2],X[5],X[3],0)),
pol.y = with( borders, c(Y[2],Y[5],Y[3],0)) 
))
eggs$east <- as.logical(sp::point.in.polygon( 
point.x = eggs$X, point.y = eggs$Y,
pol.x = with( borders, c(X[3],X[5],X[4],X[5]*10)),
pol.y = with( borders, c(Y[3],Y[5],Y[4],Y[5])) 
))
eggs$egg.num <- 1:nrow(eggs)
eggs$p.south <- round(100*cumsum(eggs$south)/eggs$egg.num,2)
eggs$p.west <- round(100*cumsum(eggs$west)/eggs$egg.num,2)
eggs$p.north <- round(100*cumsum(eggs$north)/eggs$egg.num,2)
eggs$p.east <- round(100*cumsum(eggs$east)/eggs$egg.num,2)
eggs}
p.April09.5 <- pEggs( April09.5 )
```

The error message that I'm getting is:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "egg.num", value = 1:0) :
replacement has 2 rows, data has 0

From what I've managed to find online so far this isn't actually an issue with the data table itself, but rather something totally different. I just can't figure out what.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Please edit the post to include the data, or at least an extract of it, so we can see the problem for ourselves. You can use `dput(April09.5)` and post the output. Otherwise it it quite hard to help. It might also help if you can explain what the code is supposed to do,.